# What to set for Spring's @PropertySource when using spring.config.location command line arg?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-properties

I have defined a `@Config` class like so:

```
@Config
@PropertySource(value = "")
public class Foo {
...
}
```

I run my program by including the following:

```
 --spring.config.location=file:///Users/dev/workspace/application.yml
```

The problem is that I cannot omit the 'value' attribute of the PropertySource annotation. Why do you need to set that? Will that overwrite what I have set in `--spring.config.location`? Should I use `SimpleCommandLinePropertySource` instead of `--spring.config.location`?

Comment: Why would you need to set it? Spring Boot already takes care of loading the proper `application.properties` based on the `spring.config.location` property.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I'm new to Spring. Can you elaborate please? I need the properties to be external (located separate to the jars).

Comment: As stated Spring Boot will take care of that. I suggest a read of the Spring Boot [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) which explains this. You don't need the `@PropertySource` assuming you are loading an `application.properties`.

Comment: That's correct. I have since removed it. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use external property file using spring.config.location you just have to set for value in your configuration class:

```
@Config
@PropertySource(value = "${spring.config.location}")
public class Foo {
...
}
```